# Cataloging multiple types under one index using plone.indexer

Tags: python, plone

In `configure.zcml` I have:

```
<adapter name="getCountry" factory=".extender.country_indexer" />
```

In `extender.py` I have:

```
@indexer(IATFile)
@indexer(IATImage)
@indexer(IProject)
@indexer(IATDocument)
def country_indexer(context):
    return _country_indexer(context)
```

But this does *not* catalog all those types under the `getCountry` index.

If I comment out all but one decorator, it works for that type.

How do I manage to catalog all of them?

Some more info. Only one of the registrations is called with the proper callable. The others are called with DelegatingIndexerFactory:

```
indexer.__init__ <plone.indexer.decorator.indexer instance at 0xafa6998> (<InterfaceClass Products.ATContentTypes.interfaces.file.IATFile>,)
indexer.__init__ <plone.indexer.decorator.indexer instance at 0xafa6f80> (<InterfaceClass Products.ATContentTypes.interfaces.image.IATImage>,)
indexer.__init__ <plone.indexer.decorator.indexer instance at 0xafa8050> (<InterfaceClass project.interfaces.project.IProject>,)
indexer.__init__ <plone.indexer.decorator.indexer instance at 0xafa8128> (<InterfaceClass Products.ATContentTypes.interfaces.document.IATDocument>,)
indexer.__call__ <plone.indexer.decorator.indexer instance at 0xafa8128> <function country_indexer at 0xafa76e0>
indexer.__call__ <plone.indexer.decorator.indexer instance at 0xafa8050> <plone.indexer.delegate.DelegatingIndexerFactory object at 0xafa5910>
indexer.__call__ <plone.indexer.decorator.indexer instance at 0xafa6f80> <plone.indexer.delegate.DelegatingIndexerFactory object at 0xafa5b90>
indexer.__call__ <plone.indexer.decorator.indexer instance at 0xafa6998> <plone.indexer.delegate.DelegatingIndexerFactory object at 0xafa5910>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the `@indexer` decorator does not support chaining.

There are several possible solutions:

#### 1. Marker interface (My Favorite)

Mark the content, which support `_country_indexer` with a separate marker interface. 
For example `ICountry`?

This can be done with ZCML:

```xml
<class class="dotted.name.to.my.class">
      <implements interface="dotted.name.to.ICountry" />
</class>
```

Then use this interface for the `indexer`

```python
@indexer(ICountry)
def country_indexer(context):
    return _country_indexer(context)
```

#### 2. Register on `Interface` and implement the logic directly into the method:

```python
@indexer(Interface)
def country_indexer(context):
    SUPPORTED = [IATFile, IATImage, IProject, IATDocument]
    ...
```

#### 3. Duplicate your code several times

```python
@indexer(IATDocument)
def country_indexer_at_doc(context):
    return _country_indexer(context)

@indexer(IATFile)
def country_indexer_at_file(context):
    return _country_indexer(context)

@indexer(IATImage)
def country_indexer_at_img(context):
    return _country_indexer(context)

...
```

And the zcml part:

```xml
<adapter name="getCountry" factory=".extender.country_indexer_at_doc" />
<adapter name="getCountry" factory=".extender.country_indexer_at_file" />
<adapter name="getCountry" factory=".extender.country_indexer_at_img" />
...
```

Comment: You answer if good, but the **best** solution will be to fix that stuff in indexer implementation, adding chaining support.

Comment: Agree with @keul :-)  This was my first naïve try: https://gist.github.com/jean/b59c2b74e17bbe487091

Comment: @Mathias, thanks. I tried **1.** but must have fumbled something, it didn't seem to work. Also, it's verbose. I don't like **2.** as it will result in tons of useless calls. I ended up with **3.** which works, but ... ugh. Hmm I see you repeat the same function name. Does that work?? I'll give it a try later.

Comment: Yes you should go for the first one. Just to clearify: You have to define the `ICountry` interface by yourself. `dotted.name.to.my.class` means in your case the dotted name to ATFile, ATImage, etc.